# Cannot build a Swift project AppDelegate.swift fails

Tags: swift, xcode, github, project, appdelegate

I need some help, I cannot find the build error after hours, when I try to compilate it shows me an error, could someone help me please? I leave the link below. Thanks in advance!

[My project in GitHub](https://github.com/paulertion/RecipesBel.git)

Comment: You have a lot of breaking constraints. But I cannot see any error. Would you please provide more information about the error you're seeing and where it appears?

Comment: Can you please share the error over here, instead of us searching in your project.

Comment: Thanks for reply both! I can't copy the entire error that's why I shared my project. It breaks when I run it.

Comment: run your project perfectly. xcode(11.3). when I just click on your first list item app crash and i found that you set "PlateCell" instead of "RecipeCell" in your storyboard's PlateViewController.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot @RuchiMakadia :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Command + Shift + K to clean the build folder

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you have a lot of breaking constraints, but your project builds successfully in xCode 11.3.1. Consider deleting derived data from you xCode.

Comment: Yes it builds successfully but still crashes after clear the build folder